# Capybara click method passing parameters results in not a key modifier error

Tags: selenium-webdriver, capybara

I'm trying to use the Capybara Node::Element click with the offset as defined in the Rdoc.

Basically, I want to use the click method on an element, but clicking NOT on the center of the element, but offset to the left. I don't want to do the action.move_to methods.

```
#click(*key_modifiers = [], offset = {x: nil, y: nil}) ⇒ Capybara::Node::Element
Click the Element

Parameters:

*key_modifiers (Array<:alt, :control, :meta, :shift>) (defaults to: []) 
— Keys to be held down when clicking
  offset (Hash) (defaults to: {x: nil, y: nil}) — x and y coordinates 
  to offset the click location from the top left corner of the element. 
  If not specified will click the middle of the element.
```

I'm just not sure how to use this if I want the default key_modifier ('[ ]'). When I try this, I get a not a key modifier error.

```
elem = find(some_xpath)
elem.click([], {x: -20, y: nil})

 ArgumentError:
 [] is not a modifier key, expected one of [:control, :shift, :alt, 
 :command, :meta]
```

I tried skipping [] and it doesn't seem to do the offset

```
elem.click({x: -100 y:nil})
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify both x any y, you can't specify `nil` for one of them

```
click(x: -100, y: 0)
```

Comment: I got it to work, question - what are the x, y values relative from? I was thinking it was from the element center since that is the default. But seems that is not the case since -100 did not work, I had to put (+) positive values.

Comment: @ibaralf It's from the top left corner of the element, as stated in the docs - https://www.rubydoc.info/github/teamcapybara/capybara/Capybara/Node/Element#click-instance_method.  The WebDriver spec recently changed to specify the offset should be from the center of the element so this may change in Capybara 4 - but for Capybara 3.x it's staying as from the top left corner.

Comment: As of version 3.38.0 (released 2022-11-03), w3c_click_offset now defaults to true. This means that the offset is from the centre of the node.